# System of logs for my site

Tags: php, symfony, logging, printing

I create a small class for save the logs of my website. My log class :

```
class Logs {

public static function  writeFile($message)
{
    $log_path = '/home/vagrant/Workspace/symfony/app/logs';
    // Set path:
    $log_path .= '/' . date('Ymd');
    $log_path .= '.log';
    $s_message = date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . ' (' . microtime(true) . ') ' . $message;
    $s_message .= "\n";
    file_put_contents($log_path, $s_message, FILE_APPEND);
}
public static function logInfo($s_message)
{
    self::writeFile($s_message);
}

}
```

And I call the static method in my controller :

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $categories = $em->getRepository('EnsJobeetBundle:Category')->getWithJobs();
    $test = array(
        '1'=>'1',
        '2'=>'2',
        '3'=>'3'
    );
    Logs::logInfo(print_r($test));

    return $this->render('EnsJobeetBundle:Job:index.html.twig', array(
        'categories' => $categories
    ));
}
```

The problem is that : in my view it's show this $test array and in my log is write only the first value of array, so the value 1.
What I'm doing wrong? Help me please! Thx in advance!

Comment: Hi @Gigel if mine or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accordion with the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php):

> If you would like to capture the output of print_r(), use the return
>   parameter. When this parameter is set to TRUE, print_r() will return
>   the information rather than print it.

Use this:

```
Logs::logInfo(print_r($test, true));
```

instead of:

```
Logs::logInfo(print_r($test));
```

hope this help

I suggest you to use  `Monolog`  for this task

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html

Comment: It's a problem when I tried to make : Logs::logInfo(print_r($categories,true)) doesn't work

Comment: very strage, can you try with [var_export](http://php.net/var_export) always  with `true` parameter as second argument

Comment: I get the error : 
Error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 531365986 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

[print_r](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.print-r.php) has second parameter: `return`. Wich means will `print_r()` returns it's output, or just display it. It's false by default

So you need to try

```
  Logs::logInfo(print_r($test,true));
```